# Plot a value on the chart based on three values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following data with me:

Mean - 25
-SD -  21
+SD -  29

Value to plot = 26. How can I represent this in Excel? So imagine this like 3 columns (for Mean, -SD and +SD) with Mean in the middle and -SD and +SD on either sides, and I have to create a 4th column to represent 26 in a different color.

Here's a representation -

[image]

Comment: I have updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show one way without changing the values itself:

Make A1:E1 to `y,-SD,Mean,+SD,Value`. A2:E2 would be `0,21,25,29,26`. A3 is 1 and B3:E3 will be the same as B2:E2.

The sheet should look like this:
[image]

Now select the whole range (A1:E3) and hit scatter chart in the insert tab.
[image]

Do not get confused, you will get a chart which looks like this:
[image]

Now we right click the chart and hit "Select Data..."
[image]

In the new window we hit the middle button "switch row/column" so the chart looks like this:
[image]

This is already pretty close to what we want. To transpose it (so it looks like your picture) we need to switch all x and y values (which is a bit more of work). We again go to the "Select Data..." window. There simply select the first series (should be `-SD`) and hit edit to get another window holding the data:
[image]

We now need to set the "Series X Values:" to the range which is in "Series Y Values:" and vice versa. The series name should not be changed (it is easier to know which "line" is which).
[image]

We need to to do this "switch" for each series. so in our example the y values always should be `=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$3`. After all of that is done, the chart should look like this:
[image]

All that is left is formatting. Hide gridlines/legend/scales, change colors for the series all that stuff. I also suggest switching the the "values series" to first position in the "Select Data..."- window (so if the value is the same to +/-SD or Mean it doesn't "vanish" behind it). If everything is done, then it can look like this (just format it to fit your needs):
[image]

A copy of the Workbook is [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_752Ga6Yb7udU81OGJnSkxMeHM/view?usp=sharing).

If you have any questions, just ask ;)

Comment: You sir are awesome. I hope you know that :) Everything works great. Just one question. Is there any way to do this without duplicating the values like in Row 2 and 3?

Comment: @IWantToLearn the trick is, that you have 4 graphs which go from 0 to 1 without a change (this makes it a line). Without that you would only get dots. Still, you could do something similar with a "100% stacked bar chart", but you would need to alter the values depending on the "value". Main problem is, that the chart is transposed (different values below each other) and a normal (math) chart, can't have multiple y-values for one x-value (while having multiple x-values with the same y is ok). The scatter chart is different in this behavior. It allows to also draw lines in a not increasing order

Comment: @IWantToLearn to show this, simply enter the numbers `0, -0.7, 1, -1, 0.7, 0` and below `1.1, 0, 0.7, 0.7, 0, 1.1`. then select that range and hit in the insert-tab -> "scatter-chart" -> "scatter with straight lines". A normal mathematical chart would never allow to get a graph like this. However: we are using this here to "draw" a chart which looks like what you want. I often use it for triangle-calculations (for better showing what we do at a full scale triangle) ;)